# NSMutableURLRequest posting a JSON object to CakePHP appears as an Array

Tags: xcode, json, cakephp

I send JSON data from Xcode in the following way:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Test title", @"title",
        @"Test option1", @"option1",
        @"Test option2", @"option2", nil];
NSError *error;
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somedomain.com/posts/add"];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I write the received data in CakePHP to a file in the following way:

```
public function add()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
        if ($this->RequestHandler->requestedWith('json')) {
            file_put_contents('debug.txt', print_r($this->request->data, true));
        }
    }
}
```

and the data in the file ('debug.txt') looks like this:

**Array
(
    [option2] => Test option2
    [title] => Test title
    [option1] => Test option1
)**

I know that the data being sent is in JSON format and I expect the received data to appear as JSON format rather than an Array in 'debug.txt'. Is this a correct assumption and if so what is going wrong?

Comment: From the above code nothing is looking wrong in ios side code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is here, before you can do anything with that data in PHP you'd have to convert it to an array anyway, it seems the CakePHP requesthandler is doing this automatically for you.

If you really want the original json just `json_encode()` it back again.

Comment: It's actually not a problem. As you say I do need the data as an array eventually. I just wanted to know why the data appears as an array. Your suggestion that the RequestHandler is automatically converting it may be correct. I didn't see any documentation with regards to this though. Cheers.